# Multi table Inheritance on rails (active record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, multiple-inheritance

I am trying implement a Multi table Inheritance. In my situation I am trying modeling Appliances. Appliances have common attributes like price, name and model but there are different types of appliances like TV, Freezer, Fridge with different attributes (temperature, size, etc...).

I search and I found this gem https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as. What you think ? What is the best way to implement this ? There is other pattern to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Single Table Inheritance quite a bit and it works really well.

However in this case, you can have one table with common attributes and then different tables for the attributes that are not shared. You can specify the relationship in inherited models.

Or you can have a single table with a serialised column to store different attributes. But that will get clunky if you try to do a search on them.

Probably Multi Table Inheritance will be the best way to go

The only way to know if the gem is good is to try it